# How do I make task wait for completion in Swift 3

Tags: swift3, xcode8, alamofire, ios10

I'm using Alamofire to send a login request to an HTTP server. It returns a JSON response. My problem is that the mainline code finishes before the .responseJSON. How do I wait until the response is returned before returning from the function?

```
var ret: Bool = true
Alamofire.request(
        URL(string: "http://localhost:8081/login/iPhone")!,
        method: .post,
        parameters: ["email":"test@test.test", "password":"test", "uuid":String(describing: UIDevice.current.identifierForVendor!.uuidString)],
        headers: [:])
    .validate()
    .responseJSON{(response) -> Void in
        do {
            guard response.result.isSuccess else {
                throw FieldError.fetchError(responseError: response.result.error)
            }
            guard let value = response.result.value as? [String: Any],
                    let status = value["status"] as? String,
                    let message = value["message"] as? String else {
                throw FieldError.messageFormatError
            }
            switch status {
                case "Login suggess":
                    break
                default:
                    throw FieldError.fieldServerError(status: status, message: message)
            }
        } catch {
            ret = false
            debugPrint(error)
        }
    }
return ret
```

Comment: The code reaches the return statement before executing the do in the .responseJSON.

Comment: Don't wait. Use a completion handler to return the boolean return value and the error.

Comment: I assume that the block in the responseJSON IS a completion handler.The problem is how to prevent the login process on the IOS platform from completing before the completion handler completes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use global

```
typealias DownloadComplete = () -> ()
```

next in func with you're json

```
func yourFunc(completed: @escaping DownloadComplete)
```

and after download use

```
completed()
```

Comment: That did it. I actually missed the completed()